# In R list ,how to set sub list names

Tags: r, list, names

How to set list names ,here is the code as below.
Currently,`split_data`  include two sub list `[[1]]` and `[[2]]`, how set names separately for them?
I want set name 'A' for `[[1]]`,'B' for  `[[2]]`, so can retrieve data use `split_data['A']`...
Anyone can help on this, thanks ?
for instance `ma <- list(a=c('a1','a2'),b=c('b1','b2'))` can use `ma["a"]` for sub list

```
library(tidyverse)
test_data <- data.frame(category=c('A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'),
                        sales=c(1,2,4,5,8,1,4,6))

split_data <- test_data %>% group_split(category)
```

Comment: According to the documentation of `group_split()` tidyverse developers intentionally do not want the list elements to be named (they can be annoying sometimes ...) so you could use the base function `split()`, in your case `test_data %>% split(test_data[['category']])` which returns a named list.

Comment: @qdread - or use the neater formula interface `test_data %>% split(~ category)`.

Comment: @Ritchie Sacramento  test_data %>% split(~ category)  seems can't work  ,it show " Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) :   unique() applies only to vectors"

Comment: @anderwyang - sorry, should have mentioned that this is a relatively new feature (since R 4.1.0) so if you're seeing that error then you need to update R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have shown you in the comments how to get what you want using `split()` instead of `group_split()`. That seems like the easiest solution.

However, if you're stuck with the existing code, here's an alternative that keeps your current code, and adds the names.

```
library(tidyverse)
test_data <- data.frame(category=c('A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'),
                        sales=c(1,2,4,5,8,1,4,6))

split_data <- test_data %>% group_split(category)


names(split_data) <- test_data %>% group_by(category) %>% group_keys() %>% apply(1, paste, collapse = ".")
```

The idea is to use `group_by` to split in the same way `group_split` does, then extract the keys as a tibble.  This will have one row per group, but will have the different variables in separate columns, so I put them together by pasting the columns with a dot as separator.  The last expression in the pipe is equivalent to `apply(keys, 1, f)`
where `f` is `function(row) paste(row, collapse = ".")`.  It applies `f` to each row of the tibble, producing a single name.

This should work even if the split happens on multiple variables, and produces names similar to those produced by `split()`.

Comment: this is great . but i an little confused  about [apply(1, paste, collapse = ".")] ,how to understand it ? Thanks!

Comment: I've edited it to add an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for you replay . This is greate